# Where can I download MongoDB for OS X 32 bit

Tags: macos, mongodb

I was looking at http://www.mongodb.org/downloads, but I couldn't see the the 32bit version for OS X. There are 32 bit ones for Linux and Windows. Is there only 64 bit one supported by MacOS. I have a 32 bit MacOS 10.6 Snow Leopard. How should I proceed?

Comment: One way would be to build from source. Instructions are here: http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: If you plan to use MongoDB in production, you should not use the 32bit version, as it has a 2GB limitation: http://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/#operations. If you just need it to try out something, then you should build it from source

Answer (score 2):

Although not linked to from the main site, you can find all MongoDB downloads for 32-bit Mac OS X at http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/osx/i386 Version 2.3 is the latest download available as of Jan 2014. I have the same setup as you - 32-bit Mac OS 10.6 Snow Leopard. Playing around the link for archived downloads I realized that:

- http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/osx gives all OS X downloads (32 and 64 bit)
- Appending /i386 to that link will filter and show only those downloads containing i386 in the title
- Appending /x86_64 will similarly show only 64 bit downloads

Hope that helps!

Comment: The last i386 version is mongodb-osx-i386-2.3.0.tgz in 2012!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the automated builds for 32bit OS X have been stopped or at least the url schema has been changed. Version 2.0.4 was the last working version I found a link for:

http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-i386-2.0.4.tgz